# iOS: How to get pointer to navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm obviously missing something...

In my iOS app, I push a UIViewController onto a navigation controller:

```
MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController"];
[self.navigationController mvc animated:YES];
```

MyViewController displays fine, and I can see and use the navigationBar, but when I try to get a pointer back to the navigation controller from within my view controller, I get a nil result.

```
UINavigationController *nav = [self navigationController];
if (!nav) {
    NSLog(@"no nav");
}
```

I've been beating my head against this all day, but can't see that I'm doing anything wrong. I get no warnings or errors in Xcode. Am I completely missing something?

TIA: john

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `navigationController` won't be set properly on `viewDidLoad`. You have to check it in `viewDidAppear` or at some later stage. Which method are you calling to `[self navigationController]` in?

The reason for this is that when `viewDidLoad` is called, the `UINavigationController` is still processing the `pushViewController:animated:` method. It would appear to set the `navigationController` property *after* it initialises the controller's `view`. I can't recall whether the property is set by the time `viewWillAppear` runs, but it should definitely be set by `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Ah! Of course. I bet that's the problem. I'm checking it in the initializer, which is far too early. Duh! Thank you for saving my poor head!

Answer (score 0):

```
id rootViewController = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder];
```